# conflicting focus on two fields inside the ajax success function used for validation

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have used ajax for validation on field blur (focus if invalid), but it conflicts with the ajax validation on next field

1.Tried setting a global variable and checking it in the next field validation.
2. Stored $(this) in variable and also called event on bind method.
3. Tried disabling other fields when focus is on current field but does not work on certain conditions.

```
$('input[name="ledgercode"]')
.bind(
'blur',
   '#ledgercode',
function(e) {
if ($('#dialog1').dialog('isOpen')) {
    e.preventDefault();
} else {
    $this = $(this);
var ledgercd = $(this).val();
if (ledgercd == "") {                            
   document.getElementById("msgbox1").innerHTML = "Code must be entered";

  $(this).focus();
  } else {
  $.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'GL_Servlet?method=ledger_validation',
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
    "json" : [ ledgercd,company ]
},
   success : function(data) {
    var ldgstat = (data.ldgstat);
    if (ldgstat == false) {
$this.focus(); //consistent focus if value invalid
    document.getElementById("msgbox1").innerHTML = "Invalid Code";
} else if (data.ldgstat == true) {
$('#txt_ldg_name').val(data.ldg_desc);
$this.closest("tr")
.find('input[name="ldg_desc"]').val(data.ldg_desc);
    document.getElementById("msgbox1").innerHTML = "";
}
    }                                            
   });
}
}
   });
```

If value on field is invalid the field should remain focused and not leave field till right value is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Setting (async : false,) in ajax issue is resolved.